# JQuery - show second checkbox when ticking first

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my simple example I'm currently stuck on. I'm trying to get a 2nd checkbox to appear, if I click on the first one.

In the example below (demo: https://jsfiddle.net/d2ykzjvg/1/) you can see that both checkboxes appear when the page loads.

If I click the red one saying "1st" then nothing happens. If I remove the tick from the first checkbox, the blue "2nd" box is hidden.

If I then tick the red one again, the blue one appears, and toggles on and off when I toggle the red checkbox.

I don't know how to get the blue checkbox to be hidden when the page first loads.

**HTML**

```
    <form action="#" method="post">
        <div class="label label-danger">
            <label for="rev"><input id="rev" type="checkbox" name="rev" id="rev" value="y"> 1st</label>
        </div>
        <div class="label label-primary" id="r2">
            <label for="rev_inc"><input type="checkbox" name="rev_inc" id="rev_inc" value="y"> 2nd</label>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function() {

    $('#rev').change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $('#r2').show();
        }
    else{
            $('#r2').hide();
        }
    });

});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d2ykzjvg/1/

Comment: Either explicitly make `#r2` hidden (by adding a style), or trigger your change handler on page load - https://jsfiddle.net/d2ykzjvg/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put an inline style in your second div like this

```
 <div class="label label-primary" id="r2" style="display:none;">
        <label for="rev_inc"><input type="checkbox" name="rev_inc" id="rev_inc" value="y"> 2nd</label>
 </div>
```

Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/d2ykzjvg/2/

Answer (score 2):

You should use `style="display:none"` like this:

```
<label for="rev_inc"><input type="checkbox" name="rev_inc" id="rev_inc" value="y" style="display:none;"> 2nd</label>
```

In order to hide it on page-load

Answer (score 1):

You need to hide first your 2nd checkbox

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#r2').hide();
    $('#rev').change(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $('#r2').show();
        }
        else {
            $('#r2').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple. Just add `$('#r2').hide();` this on page load function.

OR add this css below:

```
#r2{
     display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the div on "documentReady" or you can add style ( display : none )

```
$(function() {
    $('#r2').hide();
    $('#rev').change(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $('#r2').show();
        } else {
            $('#r2').hide();
        }
    });

});
```

or

```
<style>
 #r2 { display:none; }
</style>
```